# How to sort a list of files found by Windows 10 search by date modified?

Tags: windows-10, search

I am gradually coming to terms with Windows 10 search, and have got as far as creating an index on the correct data and being able to search for e.g. doc:something in the "type here to search" box at the bottom left to get a list of files matching that criteria.

What I have not found a way to do is to view that that list in explorer and sort as desired.  There is a "search in file explorer" link at the bottom, but it just seems to run the same search again and doesn't find anything.  A manual search in the correct directory does find what I'm expecting to see, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get to that from the "Type here to search" box.

Comment: Actually, the "search in file explorer" link at the bottom, doesn't just run the same search again - it runs a different search that doesn't always find anything, so it's even less useful.

Answer (score 9):

Change the display in Explorer to *Details*, instead of the *Search* multiline default. Then click on the header for *Date*. Unfortunately, Windows will perform the search all over again, rather than just sorting the existing results.

An alternative is a third-party indexed search engine, such as DocFetcher, which aslo can index file types thatWindows cannot.

Answer (score 1):

As of the current version of Windows 10, you can perform a search then right click off the search results (e.g., to the right of or below the search results displayed) and select View > Details.  Then you can sort by "Date Modified" (or any other column/metric displayed or added thereafter) as you would any list of files (e.g., within a folder).